# Add horizontal scrollbar to div with gridview?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

My webform has 3 `<div>`: The left `div` is `width: 300px` and the second div is `width: 160px`. The third `div` does not have a set width because it contains a gridview that can change in size. In other words, the gridview can have any amount of columns and each column must be 200px wide.

In this example, `GridViewClicks` has 10 columns at 200px width each. My screen is 1366x768, and 460px (300px+160px) is already taken up by two divs. The remaining space cannot display the 2000px gridview (10 cols x 200px). So it moves the third div to the bottom. And even when moving the div to the bottom, it automativally shrinks the columns. If I change `columnNumber` to *4* then the `GridViewClicks` fits.

I need to display `GridViewClicks` next to the first two divs, and show a **horizontal scrollbar** once the gridview width is greater than the available space. Each gridview column needs to be 200px each, no column resizing can be done.

My code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green; display:inline-block;"">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Width="278px" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 160px; height: 160px; background-color: blue; display:inline-block;">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Width="140px" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: red; display: inline-block;vertical-align: top; overflow-x: auto;">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewClicks" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridViewClicks_RowDataBound">
            </asp:GridView>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

And codebehind:

```
public partial class ToErase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        int columnNumber = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(string));
        }

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++)
        {
            row[i.ToString()] = "item " + i.ToString();
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        GridViewClicks.DataSource = table;
        GridViewClicks.DataBind();

    }
    protected void GridViewClicks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            for (int i = 0; i < drv.Row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Width = 200;
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Height = 80;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding the 'max-width' property to the third div you prevent it from exceeding 800px (the width of 4 columns which fits).

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green; display:inline-block;"">
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Width="278px" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 160px; height: 160px; background-color: blue; display:inline-block;">
      <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Width="140px" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: red; max-width: 800px; display: inline-block;vertical-align: top; overflow-x: auto;">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridViewClicks" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridViewClicks_RowDataBound">
      </asp:GridView>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Were you able to test your solution before posting?

Comment: I'm using my phone at the moment, the tester I have been using doesn't cover asp. I am answering based off the fact that the max width property prevents an element from exceeding a certain width. Since the gridview is expanding the third div element, limiting it's maximum width will prevent it from spanning greater than 800px. Now you never mentioned whether you have tested it, tried this before etc?

Comment: I had tried `max-width` before. It fits all the columns in div, but it shrinks them, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp4rX.png. The columns are no longer 200px each.